# How to turn off property print settings using ezdxf?

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocad, dxf, ezdxf

I want to know how to turn off the property print setting using ezdxf.

I can hide, freeze and lock on and off.
However, printing cannot be set on or off.

```py
my_lines.on()
my_lines.off()   # switch layer off, will not shown in CAD programs/viewers
my_lines.lock()  # layer is not editable in CAD programs
my_lines.freeze()
```

Can you turn printing on and off like this?

Comment: See also docs: https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tables/layer_table_entry.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plotting (i.e. printing) flag for the layer is represented by [DXF group 290](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-D94802B0-8BE8-4AC9-8054-17197688AFDB), which accepts a value of `0` (meaning the layer is **not** plotted) or `1` (meaning the layer **is** plotted).

This DXF group is represented in ezdxf by the [`plot`](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/master/tables/layer_table_entry.html#ezdxf.entities.Layer.dxf.plot) property - as such, you can disable plotting for a layer using the code:

```py
my_lines.dxf.plot = 0
```

To turn off or freeze layers which are not set to plot, you can use the following basic for loop:

```
for lay in dwg.layers:
    if lay.dxf.plot = 0: # if layer is not plotted
        lay.off() # turn layer off
        lay.freeze() # freeze layer
```

However, since [ezdxf](/questions/tagged/ezdxf) does not test whether or not a layer is current before enabling bit `1` for DXF group `70`, you may want to include this check prior to invoking the [`freeze`](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tables/layer_table_entry.html#ezdxf.entities.Layer.freeze) method, as the current layer cannot be frozen:

```
for lay in dwg.layers:
    if lay.dxf.plot = 0: # if layer is not plotted
        lay.off() # turn layer off
        if dwg.header['$CLAYER'] != lay.dxf.name: # current layer cannot be frozen
            lay.freeze() # freeze layer
```

Obviously it would be more efficient to bound the current layer name to a local variable *outside* of the `for` loop, since this value will not change within the loop, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to execute it. Another question, Can I search for a layer that is not plotted from the layer list and hide that layer if applicable?Please let me know if possible.

Comment: You're welcome. When you state *"hide that layer"*, do you want to freeze the layer or turn the layer off? Could you elaborate on what you mean by *"if applicable"*?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain it well.

I can turn a layer off or freeze by specifying the layer name.

Here's what I want to do:

First, a layer that is not plotted is searched from among several layers.
Next, I want to perform layer off / freeze operations on the found layer.

Comment: I have updated my answer above - I hope I have correctly understood your intentions. @mozman Kudos on the ezdxf library.

Comment: I tried to execute the code I said but received an error (ezdxf.lldxf.const.DXFValueError: 290, ezdxf.lldxf.const.DXFValueError: DXFAttrib 'plot' does not exist.).

Comment: @leez Sorry, I missed out the `dxf` in the code - I have updated the above.

Comment: I tried with the code that taught me, but I just got an error.
It works well for the plot = 0 layer, but there is an error for the plot = 1 layer.

For the time being,
try: ...
except:
    None
I was able to execute the process.

Thank you!